# Are Dialog Boxes & Message Boxes "Added Controls"?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dialog

When you call `MessageBox.Show()` or `Form.ShowDialog()` or `Form.Show()` is the form/ modal dialog added to the caller/parent Form or Control?  Does this only happen if you specify a parent, such as  `Form.ShowDialog(this)`?

I'm asking because I'm extending the `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` class to add additional constraints such as max # of direct children controls and only allowing specified `Type`s of Controls to be added.  I want to make sure though that Dialog & Message boxes are not affected by these constraints (unless specifically requested).  There does not seem to be much information on this topic out there; probably because none of the container controls have these restrictions out of the box.

Comment: No it isn't. The only reference in this situation is an MDI container.. which is accessible via the `Parent` property of a form. Other than that.. they aren't added to a control collection of any kind.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Thanks! That was the answer I was hoping to hear. If you change your comment to an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

No ! Dialog boxes are not added to the caller/parent Form or Control.